# Do apps installed on HDD run slower than if installed on SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance, storage

I have an Acer Aspire V Nitro Black Edition Laptop. It has a 256Gb SSD unit, where Windows 10 is installed, and a 1Tb HDD for data storage. After installing some software into the default Program Data folders, I'm running out of free space on my SSD, so I think of moving the software to the HDD. Would that affect their performance?

Most important apps I care about are DaVinci Resolve video editor, Darktable photo editor, and Ableton Live music production software.

Comment: omg, 3 reviewers think this question is opinion based?!?! *Most important apps I care about are DaVinci Resolve video editor, Darktable photo editor, and Ableton Live music production software.* Try using DaVinci Resolve and Darktable on an HDD if you think this question is opinion based..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSD's are faster than traditional disks. That's for sure. But to fully understand the answer to this question, you need to know how the operating system works.

When you perform actions, the most disk access comes from windows itself. So the biggest speedboost you get is when Windows itself runs from the SSD.

When you launch a program, the program is copied entirely into memory, and run from there. The larger your program is, the slower your program will startup if it starts from a traditional HDD vs an SSD.

Once the program started, all actions it performs from there can be slowed down if the actions are: reading from disk. But if the program does all kinds of calculations, it will not slow down.

Because it is different per program, it is going to be hard to tell you if and how much slow down there is going to be. For small programs, it is generally not a problem to have them on your slower HDD, but for things like the video editor, keep in mind, that if you store your videos on a slow medium, it will heavily affect the speed of the program. If the video editor also reads its own files during use AND the video clips are also on the slow medium, it will negatively impact performance. The program should be loaded fully into memory, but it may write a logfile to its own folder for example, or have a cache folder in its own folder.

But as with any problem, if there's no harm in doing this and you can go back, why not try and see how the performance is, and if its bad, go back to the previous state?

If you don't yet own the HDD and you are considering to buy the storage and are now thinking either of a large HDD vs a small SSD, go for a slower SSD with higher capacity, because for what you want to do, it does not really matter how fast the SSD is going to be.

Comment: according to this, I'll move some of my not indispensable software to HDD. I have a heavy and resource consuming game installed, so it will make a good "guinea pig" to check if it runs much slower on HDD.

Comment: @Lisan games are notorious for loading a lot of data, so games are one of the few programs that will definitely benefit from running on an SSD, but it are only the loading times that will improve, not the actual gaming performance.

Comment: I tried the game on HDD and, as expected, the loading times became longer, but I don't notice lagging in gameplay. So keeping the SSD for essencial software which has to be fast access seems to be the best choice

Answer (score 2):

No reason to overcomplicate matters.

Simply, Yes. 
Performance will be affected if you move them to a slower drive.
Keep your design editing and video content on the fastest drive you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SSDs are consistently faster, and reliability issues common to early SSDs have been solved, so you can expect your SSD will last as long as your HDD.

Instead, you could move Windows space-consuming functions over to that HDD to make more room on the SSD. Start by moving your TEMP and TMP files,

> Hit Start, type “system,” and then hit Enter or click the result
>   In the System window, click the “Advanced system settings” link
>   In System Properties, on the “Advanced” tab, click  “Environmental Variables”  > The top box shows user variables for the current user. 
>   Change those locations to D:\TEMP (assuming D: is your HDD).
>   Logout, repeat for other users
>   Reboot

as well as moving your old and future Windows Recovery images to the HDD, then deleting the original recovery partition

> Search on "recovery drive" in the search box
>   Pick "Create a recovery drive"  and the recovery drive tool will oprn
>   Choose "Copy the recovery partition from the PC to the recovery drive"
>   Pick "Next", select the HDD, then click "Next"
>   Pick "Create". It copies the recovery partition to the HDD.
>   Open Disk Management, delete the recovery partition, & expand C: into that space

That could give you some more elbow room until it's practical to get a larger SSD.

Comment: Then purchasing a larger SSD is recommended.

Comment: So, I can just move my recovery images. Is it the case?

Comment: If that would give you the space you need, yes